# Search form with multiple criteria , Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a search form with multiple criteria but it doesn't work, and I think the controller does not receive the form because when I click Button Submit the page reloads only.

This is the **Controller**

```
/**
* @ParamConverter("agence", options={"mapping": {"agence_slug":"slug"}})
*/
public function indexAction(Agence $agence, Request $request)
{

    $form = $this->createForm(new SearchTravelType());

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $criteria = $form->getData();
            $listTravels = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Travel')->getListBy($criteria, $agence); 

        }
    }

    $listTravels = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Travel')->findByAgence($agence);

    return $this->render('ProjectDashboardBundle:Travel:index.html.twig',
    array(
        'listTravels' => $listTravels,
        'agence' => $agence,
        'form' => $form->createView() ,
    ));
}
```

and this is the **queryBuilder**

```
class TravelRepository extends EntityRepository
{

public function getListBy($criteria, $agence)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t');
    $qb = $this->whereAgence($qb, $agence);
    $qb ->leftJoin('t.airport', 'a')
        ->addSelect('a');

    foreach ($criteria as $field => $value) {
        if (!$this->getClassMetadata()->hasField($field)) {
            // Make sure we only use existing fields (avoid any injection)
            continue;
        }

        $qb ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('t.'.$field, ':t_'.$field))
            ->setParameter('t_'.$field, $value);
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}

public function whereAgence (\Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder $qb, $agence)
{
    $qb->where('a.agence = :agence')
       ->setParameter('agence', $agence);

    return $qb;
}   

}
```

and this is the page twig and the form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form"  method="post" >
   <td>{{ form_widget(form.id) }}</td>
   <td class="center">-</td>
   <td>{{ form_widget(form.title) }}</td>
   <td>{{ form_widget(form.country) }}</td>
   <td>{{ form_widget(form.destination) }}</td>
   <td>{{ form_widget(form.airport) }}</td>
   <td>{{ form_widget(form.departureDate) }}</td>
   <td>{{ form_widget(form.returnDate) }}</td>
   <td>{{ form_widget(form.price) }}</td>
   <td>{{ form_widget(form.enabled) }}</td>
   <td><span class="input-group-btn">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple btn-sm">Search
   <i class="icon-search icon-on-right bigger-110"></i></button>
  </span>
</form>
```

I think the first problem is that form is not recovered in the controller, I tried with

```
$listTravels = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Travel')->find(1);
```

instead

```
getListBy($criteria, $agence)
```

to see what gives. the controller ignores the form and it goes directly to the following queries

```
$listTravels = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Travel')->findByAgence($agence);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can remove `$request = $this->getRequest();` from action as you are passing REquest object to this action;
2. You need to add action to your form,

like this:

```
$this->createForm(new SearchTravelType(), null, [
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('ROUT')
]);
```

or like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form"  method="post" action="{{ path('ROUT') }}" >
```

**EDIT:**

We create a filter form with GET method (you should use POST method for inserting to DB, not for fetching results), disable CSRF protection. We create a controller action:

```
public function indexAction(Agence $agence, Request $request)
{

    $form = $this->createForm(new SearchTravelType(), null, [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('ROUTE'),
        'method' => 'GET'
    ]);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $criteria = explode('&', $request->query->get($form->getName())); // I didn't test this line, you should check it..

        $listTravels = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Travel')->getListBy($criteria, $agence);

        // Terminate the request
        return $this->render('ProjectDashboardBundle:Travel:index.html.twig',
        array(
            'listTravels' => $listTravels,
            'agence' => $agence,
            'form' => $form->createView() ,
        ));
    }

    $listTravels = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Travel')->findByAgence($agence);

    return $this->render('ProjectDashboardBundle:Travel:index.html.twig',
    array(
        'listTravels' => $listTravels,
        'agence' => $agence,
        'form' => $form->createView() ,
    ));
}
```

Comment: @hous what version are you using?

Comment: @hous `bind` method has been depricated, you should use `handleRequest` instead.. And also check for form errors with `var_dump($form->getError(true))` after `handleRequest`..

Comment: I think the first problem is that form is not recovered in the controller, I tried with `->find(1)` instead `find($criteria, $agence)` like this `$listTravels = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Travel')->find(1);` to see what gives.
the controller ignores the form and it goes directly to the following queries

Comment: you're right I forgot to stop the request. Now the form is recovered but the search doesn't work :/

Comment: @hous If the form is working properly, but search doesn't work it's probably your db query problem.. Try to generate proper `$criteria` array, and proper query.. PS// I'm not sure what returns `$form->getData()` without underlying object, usually array criteria is gotten directly from Request, not from form data..

Comment: it is not needed to specifiy the method of the form as GET is the default method.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this bundle:

https://github.com/petkopara/PetkoparaMultiSearchBundle

Provides form or service for multi criteria search in Doctrine Entity. 
In your case the form solution will solve your issue:

First in your form type just only add the MultiSearchType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('search', MultiSearchType::class, array(
            'class' => 'ProjectTravelBundle:Travel'));
}
```

Then in your Controller add the following code

```
   public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->get('search');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $queryBuilder = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravel:Travel')->createQueryBuilder('e');
    $filterForm = $this->createForm('ProjectTravelBundle\Form\TravelType');

    // Bind values from the request
    $filterForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($filterForm->isValid()) {
        // Build the query from the given form object
        $queryBuilder = $this->get('petkopara_multi_search.builder')->searchForm($queryBuilder, $filterForm->get('search'));
    }

    ..
}
```

At the last render your Travel form in your template

```
{{form_render(filter_form)}}
```